# SEO редирект Django

Tags: seo, django

Привет всем было у меня так
http://site/object/id
стало
http://site/slug
Сейчас работает и так, и так. Надо перейти полностью на второй вариант что бы не потерять странички в выдаче.

Comment: Сделал через HttpResponsePermanentRedirect Правильно же?

Comment: Правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал через HttpResponsePermanentRedirect.

Answer (score 0):

Обычным 301 редиректом разве эту проблему не решить?